# Is the week before and after Easter major vacation weeks in France?

Tags: france, paris, vacations

I'll be in Paris over Easter and I'm wondering how crowded musueums and attractions will be the week before and after Easter.  Does anyone have any sense of whether or not these are major vacation times (school holidays for example)?  I know that August is a month where many (most?) french workers have vacation.  I have no idea about other times.

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of school holidays, what are traditionally considered the “Easter holidays” (vacances de Pâques), but are now called “Spring holidays” start this year (2018) on the 7th, 14th or 21st of April (depending on the “zone” one is in), and last for 2 weeks, so they’re at least one week after the Easter week-end.

Easter Monday is a public holiday in France. However Good Friday isn’t.

For “touristy” stuff like museums, monuments and other attractions, you may want to consider whether there are significant holidays in other neighbouring countries. In the UK for instance, Easter week-end is the only yearly 4-day week-end, so that may have an influence.